# nginx location regex rule not working

Tags: regex, nginx

We are trying to create a location rule on nginx side, but its not working as expected. Below is the location rule

```
 location ~* ".*\.legalcontent\.html\?path=\/legal\/.*" {
     return 200 'regex rule'; //Using this temporarily to confirm if rule is triggering
 }
```

Incoming URL is below, want to capture (**.legalcontent.html?path=/legal/**)

`https://www.mycompany.com/myapp/myproduct/mysubpage.legalcontent.html?path=/legal/somepage`

Tested regex separately on [regex tool](https://regex101.com/), seems to be good

[image]

But its not working, tried simple context roots to check if everything else is good.

```
# Following simple rules works fine, but we want location to kick-in 
# only for specific condition
location /myapp {
    return 200 'myapp rule';
}

location /myapp/myproduct {
    return 200 'myapp myproduct rule';
}
```

Is there a way to handle location rule for this kind of input URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `location` will only check the path of the request. To check the arguments you must create a conditional with the `$args` variable.

```
location ~* ".*\.legalcontent\.html$" {
    if ($args ~* "^path=\/legal\/.*") {
        return 200 'regex rule';
    }
}
```